# Getting the ref from a dynamic component when using Redux, React and react-router-dom 4.x

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-v4

I have the following class

```
class MatchBox extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.countdownHandler = null;
        this.showBlocker = true;

        this.start = this.start.bind(this);
    }

    start() {
        ...
    }

    render() {
        ...

        return (
            <div style={ styles.mainContainer } className="fluid-container">
                ...
            </div>
        );
    }
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    ...
}

function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    ...
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps, null, { withRef: true })(MatchBox));
```

which is used in this class

```
class GameBox extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        ...
    }

    render() {
        var mainElement = null;
        switch(this.props.mainElement.element) {
            case 'SEARCHING': mainElement = <SearchingBox gameType={ this.props.gameType }/>; break;
            case 'MATCH': mainElement = <MatchBox ref='matchBox'/>; break;

            default: mainElement = <SearchingBox/>;
        }

        return (
            <div style={ styles.mainContainer } className="fluid-container">
                { mainElement }
            </div>
        );
    }
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    ...
}

function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    ...
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps, null, { withRef: true })(GameBox));
```

And I can't get the ref of the object MatchBox. I tried with `this.refs.matchBox` and is null, also tried getting directly from ref(`ref={(r) => { // r is null } }`) and I don't know what to try anymore.
I'm using react-router-dom 4 and I don't know if function `withRouter` affect the outcome component.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not pretty, but I think this is the solution. `withRouter` exposes the child ref via a `wrappedComponentRef` callback, which gets us to the `connect` hoc. That exposes its child ref via `getWrappedInstance` if you pass the `withRef` attribute as you did. So you just have to combine both of those.

```
class GameBox extends React.Component {    
    matchboxRefCallback = (connectHOC) => {
        this.matchboxRef = connectHOC ? connectHOC.getWrappedInstance() : null;
    }
    render() {
        return <MatchBox wrappedComponentRef={this.matchboxRefCallback}/>;
    }
}
```

Comment: it's God's save

Answer (score 0):

Much more cleaner solution would be to create a HOC. which will forward the ref to actual component

```
const matchBoxHOC = (WrappedComponent) => {

    class MatchBoxHOC extends React.Component {
        render() {
            const { forwardRef, ...rest } = this.props;
            return <WrappedComponent {...rest} ref={forwardRef} />;
        }
    }

    const WithRouterMatchBoxHOC = withRouter(MatchBoxHOC, { withRef: true });

    return React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
        return <WithRouterMatchBoxHOC {...props} forwardRef={ref} />;
    });
}
```

Call is like

```
export default matchBoxHOC(connect(mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps, null, { withRef: true })(MatchBox));
```